# How to resolve conflict between two aplay running at the same time

Tags: command-line, sound, scripts, alsa

I use a lots of sounds in my shell-scripts, so it's not rare, when two or more scripts begin a conflict for audio channel. If one of my script already play sound and the other wants too, than it will wait until the first done. I'm using aplay and mpg123, but it seems like there is no difference for this situation. They both will wait until the other finish play sound.

But in the same script it's possible to play a multiple sounds:

```
aplay /path/to/1.wav & aplay /path/to/2.wav
```

How can I do the same thing, but for the different scripts?

Comment: Do you use the same parameters for `aplay`? Are all these scripts executed by the same user?

Comment: I guess, yes. Not sure, should I consider path to the sound as a diffirent parametr.

First script:
`aplay -q /path/to/1.wav`

Second script:
`aplay -q /path/to/2.wav`

And, yes, all of them executed by the same user.

Comment: Create three simple scripts, `play1`, `play2`, and `play12`, that just call `aplay`. Do they behave as described?

Comment: I've get a very strange result. At the first attempt, they work fine (actualy, one call mpg123, second call aplay). But then, when I run another script, which is complicated and using aplay, the problem was happened. And with all further attempts, even if I try to repeat situation from the first attempt, problem was there.

Comment: Show how exactly that complicated script runs aplay.

Comment: `aplay -q "/path/to/3.wav";  aplay -q "/path/to/4.wav" & notify-send -i "/path/to/1.png" "Title" "text"` This code repeated several times and runs after success wget with grep.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with that script?

Comment: That script works fine. The problem is, that when I run some other script, which call aplay and during it's playing I call that script, that script are execute only until the line of code with aplay. Than it's wait while other scripts aplay will be finished and continue it's own execution, starting with it's own aplay calling.